# creating multiple table in databasehelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two table that i'm creating in one database helper class 
the code is looks like this

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (" +
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                FNAME + " TEXT, " +
                LNAME + " TEXT, " +
                PNUMBER + " TEXT, " +
                EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                NIC + " TEXT" + ")";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ORDER = "CREATE TABLE " + ORDER_TABLE + " (" +
                ORD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                ORD_Name + " TEXT, " +
                ORD_Qty + " TEXT, " +
                ORD_Price + " TEXT, " +
                ORD_Location + " TEXT " + ")";


        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ORDER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ORDER_TABLE);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

        }
```

the first table is creating without a problem but the second table is not creating the logcat says no such a table do i need to have another database helper class for a seperate table

Comment: No you don't need another helper class. Probably the database was initially created with only the first table so now each time you run the app the onCreate() method of the class is never called because the database already exists. Uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun to recreate the database with both tables.

Comment: I deleted the app and cleared the cache it doesn't work the database is still there i tried it with a new virtual device then it works fine

Comment: Check your manifest. If there is this line: `android:allowBackup="true"` change it to `android:allowBackup="false"` so thedatabase is not recreated as it was because of the backup option.